# Openpyxl - checking if cell has fill

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to check if a cell is highlighted in yellow.  All the posts I've come across is to fill a cell, not check if it has a fill.  Heres my code so far:

```
coordinates = []

fl = PatternFill(patternType = "solid", fgColor="FFFFFF00", bgColor="FFFFFF00") 
print (fl)

for d in ws['A']:

    if str(d.value)[0:10] == str(last_day_of_month) and d.fill == fl:  
        coordinates.append(d.coordinate)
    elif str(d.value)[0:10] == str(previous_month) and d.fill == fl:
        coordinates.append(d.coordinate)
        break
```

I don't need to check if the cell is the correct color or not, I just need to know if its highlighted so any method to find out if the cell has a fill would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (d.font.color):
    #it's highlighted
```

Or there is another option:

```
d.fill.start_color.index
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It returned 'None'.  I was really hoping it was that easy.

Comment: @DavidVo You sure you have indicate the correct row, column etc?

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I needed.